# How to fix this syntax error in php?

Tags: php, syntax, average

I am trying to create a php file that displays the average score  out of 5 numbers for class, but when i ever I try to display it i keep getting this error

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'print' (T_PRINT) in C:\xampp\htdocs\scores.php on line 10"

```
<html>
<head>
<title> average scores </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$scorefile = fopen("scores.txt,"r")
$avgscore = (score1 +score2 + score3 + score4 + score5)/5);
fclose($scorefile);
print(<p> average score is $avgscore</p>);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fix it by closing your quotes properly

Comment: Then explain what `score1`, `score2`, `score3`, `score4` and `score5` are supposed to be?

Comment: `$scorefile = fopen("scores.txt,"r")` -> `$scorefile = fopen("scores.txt","r");`, `$avgscore = (score1 +score2 + score3 + score4 + score5)/5);` -> `$avgscore = ((score1 +score2 + score3 + score4 + score5)/5);`, 
`print(<p> average score is $avgscore</p>);` -> `print("<p> average score is $avgscore</p>");`